# How to bind selected state of an option to a boolean in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a list of select elements, where options are defines in a JSON object. I want for each option to preserve selected state in a boolean, meaning that when user select an option the "selected" value for that option becomes "true", and if user selects another option that value becomes "false".

```
<div ng-repeat="choice in choices">
            {{choice.name}}:
            <select>
                <option value="" ></option>
                <option ng-repeat="option in choice.options" ng-selected="option.selected">{{option.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Example of an option:

```
{id=1, name='option1', selected=false}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep things simple restructure your model. Something like this:

#### HTML

```
<select ng-model="selectedChoice" 
ng-options="opt as opt for (opt, obj) in options">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

#### Controller

```
$scope.options = {
    "option1":{
        id:1, 
        name:'option1', 
        selected:false
    },
    "option2":{
        id:2, 
        name:'option2', 
        selected:false
    },
    "option3":{
        id:3, 
        name:'option3', 
        selected:false
    }
}

$scope.$watch("selectedChoice",function(newVal, oldVal){
    if(!newVal) return;
    $scope.options[newVal].selected = true;
    $scope.options[oldVal].selected = false;
});
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TmWHd/)**</kbd>